# How to properly handle "out of memory" error with Wasm/JS

Tags: javascript, opencv, webassembly

I'm working on a computer-vision web-app. To do so, I use the OpenCV library in a Wasm Module as provided in [the docs](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d0/d84/tutorial_js_usage.html).
This works pretty well most of the time on my laptop/desktop. Yet, when using it on my Android phone (Firefox for Android v. 68 on a Samsung Galaxy Note III), it eventually throws a "out of memory" error on each reload.

I've tried deleting the Wasm module object onbeforeunload to empty the memory, without any luck.

Here's a basic example of what I do, straight from opencv.js doc:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
let imgElement = document.getElementById('imageSrc');
let inputElement = document.getElementById('fileInput');
inputElement.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
  imgElement.src = URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]);
}, false);
imgElement.onload = function() {
  let mat = cv.imread(imgElement);
  cv.imshow('canvasOutput', mat);
  mat.delete();
};
function onOpenCvReady() {
  document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'OpenCV.js is ready.';
}
</script>
<script async src="opencv.js" onload="onOpenCvReady();" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I won't copy/paste opencv.js here, but you'll find it [here](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/opencv.js) if needed.

On the other hand, here's how I handle tab closing/reloading:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
  delete cv.wasmMemory;
  delete cv.wasmTable;
  delete cv;
}
```

I always get this error:

```
uncaught exception: out of memory
```

To avoid it, I have to close tab, quit the browser and open it all again. It would be great if there was a way to manually empty the memory to avoid this behavior. :)

Comment: `delete` in JavaScript has nothing to do with memory management. Your first two `delete`s may free up memory *as a side effect* because they each remove a property from the `cv` object. You haven't shown how `cv` is declared/created, but if it's a declared variable (`var cv`, `let cv`, ...), `delete cv` does nothing. If you want to free up the memory used by whatever `cv` refers to, just assign something to `cv` (usually `undefined` or `null`): `cv = undefined;` **But**, there's no point to that if the page is about to be torn down; all memory allocated to the page...

Comment: ...will be reclaimed when the page environment is destroyed.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. The clarification about the `delete` keyword was in fact useful; I did try assigning undefined to the cv object. Yet, as you stated, there's no point to that since the page is about to be destroyed.
What puzzles me here is that it looks like not all memory allocated to the page is reclaimed, otherwise i wouldn't get the "out of memory" error...

Comment: It looks to me like `cv` is being called from a higher (possibly global) scope. Therefore, after you leave that page, the memory will not clear for the "higher" scoped `cv` no?

I would also do a chrome profiler on this to make sure you have correctly identified the cause of the 'out of memory' error. Even working on a local desktop / laptop you should see a significant spike in memory consumption or a leak. Using the profiler will help you identify exactly what all isn't being cleared properly.

Comment: I was on a similar situation, and it turned out to be caused be a bug on Firefox with reloading a page with DevTools open. So just closing DevTools, reloading a opening DevTools again solved it for me. See this emscripten issue for more info: https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/issues/8126